# How to perform matrix multiplication between two 3D tensors along the first dimension?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I wish to compute the dot product between two 3D tensors along the first dimension. I tried the following einsum notation:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(30).reshape(3, 5, 2)
b = np.random.randn(30).reshape(3, 2, 5)

# Expecting shape: (3, 5, 5)
np.einsum("ijk,ikj->ijj", a, b)
```

Sadly it returns this error:

```
ValueError: einstein sum subscripts string includes output subscript 'j' multiple times
```

I went with Einstein sum after I failed at it with `np.tensordot`. Ideas and follow up questions are highly welcome!

Comment: Matrix multiplication along the first axis/dimension sounds like you just want `a @ b`, which will perform matrix multiplication `(5, 2) x (2, 5)` for each of the three pairs from `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two dimensions of size `5` and `5` do not correspond to the same axes. As such you need to use two different subscripts to designate them. For example, you can do:

```
>>> res = np.einsum('ijk,ilm->ijm', a, b)

>>> res.shape
(3, 5, 5)
```

---

Notice you are also required to change the subscript for axes of size `2` and `2`. This is because you are computing the batched outer product (*i.e.* we iterate on two axes at the same time), not a dot product (*i.e.* we iterate simultaneously on the two axes).

- Outer product:

  ```
  >>> np.einsum('ijk,ilm->ijm', a, b)
  ```
- Dot product over subscript `k`, which is `axis=2` of `a` and `axis=1` of `b`:

  ```
  >>> np.einsum('ijk,ikm->ijm', a, b)
  ```

  which is equivalent to `a@b`.

Comment: What is that the OP needs?  I thought he wanted `a@b`.  Your first example gets the right shape, but does so by first reducing `a` and `b` to (3,5,1) and (3,1,5), and doing the broadcasted outer.

Answer (score 1):

`dot product ... along the first dimension` is a bit unclear.  Is the first dimension a 'batch' dimension, with 3 dot's on the rest?  Or something else?

```
In [103]: a = np.random.randn(30).reshape(3, 5, 2)
     ...: b = np.random.randn(30).reshape(3, 2, 5)
In [104]: (a@b).shape
Out[104]: (3, 5, 5)
In [105]: np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',a,b).shape
Out[105]: (3, 5, 5)
```

`@Ivan's` answer is different:

```
In [106]: np.einsum('ijk,ilm->ijm', a, b).shape
Out[106]: (3, 5, 5)
In [107]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ijk,ilm->ijm', a, b), a@b)
Out[107]: False

In [108]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', a, b), a@b)
Out[108]: True
```

Ivan's sums the `k` dimension of one, and `l` of the other, and then does a broadcasted elementwise.  That is not matrix multiplication:

```
In [109]: (a.sum(axis=-1,keepdims=True)* b.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True)).shape
Out[109]: (3, 5, 5)
In [110]: np.allclose((a.sum(axis=-1,keepdims=True)* b.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True)),np.einsum('ijk,ilm->ijm', a,
     ...:  b))
Out[110]: True
```

Another test of the batch processing:

```
In [112]: res=np.zeros((3,5,5))
     ...: for i in range(3):
     ...:    res[i] = a[i]@b[i]
     ...: np.allclose(res, a@b)
Out[112]: True
```